# tslib tools don't draw anything on the screen

Tags: linux, framebuffer

Trying to calibrate touchscreen for Qt apps with tslib on ARM-device. When running ts_calibrate or ts_test, they both work (i.e. return info about touches) and ts_calibrate successfully calibrates touchscreen when touching the screen somewhere around where checkpoints should be, but the screen is just black.

Qt apps (Qt4 ones through the QWS) run fine.

Here are export params for tslib:

```
export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event1
export TSLIB_TSEVENTTYPE=INPUT
export TSLIB_CONFFILE=/etc/ts.conf
export TSLIB_CALIBFILE=/etc/pointercal
export TSLIB_CONSOLEDEVICE=none
export TSLIB_FBDEVICE=/dev/fb0
export TSLIB_PLUGINDIR=$TSLIB_PATH/ts
```

`ts.conf` file has just the default values

```
module_raw input
module pthres pmin=1
module variance delta=30
module dejitter delta=100
module linear
```

upd: Related issue of our device could be that terminal doesn't draw itself on the screen either, we're working through the COM with it.

TL;DR What could be the problem of tslib tools not drawing the picture?

Comment: Hello and welcome to http://unix.stackexchange.com If possible you can add the question to the text body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was incorrectly configured framebuffer driver to blame, probably color depth or bit setup. So terminal console just drew itself black on black and ts-calibrate tool wasn't working. Also fbcon wasn't enabled in kernel options.

Strangely Qt app worked anyway though.